# Exporting data by month/year using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-attribute, arcgis-10.6

Using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1. I have a large dataset that I need to view sequentially by month AND year. Instead of using Select by Attribute for each month/year combo (i.e. February 2017-May 2019 for 28 total feature classes).

Can this be done in ModelBuilder?

Data is currently in a file geodatabase and I'm looking to export each date/month as a feature class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the field holding your dates are of date data type, then:

- Add a text field
- Use Field Calculator to write year and month to the field, see for example: [How To: Extract a portion of the Date field](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000014933)
- [Split By Attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm) using the field as `Split_Fields`

(If the field is already text and year-month then all you need is Split By Attributes)

With Split By Attributes you probably dont need to use ModelBuilder and Iterators.

Comment: Excellent! I actually don't need to extract a date. They are two standalone columns - one as Month and one as Year. Would you suggest I concatenate the two into one new column and then use Split by Attributes?

Comment: Nice! No you can pass both fields to Split By Attributes

Comment: Yeah, I tried selecting both fields in Split By Attributes and nothing happened. I just concatenated both fields into one new column and ran it again. It worked! Thanks so much for the help!